# left join to get sum of column in second table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get sum of `Collection.Amount` from table Collection provided that there aren't entries for all `JId` but only for those `JId` which have some payment against them

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.test
AS
select JobCard.JId, sum(cast(isnull(Collection.Amount, 0) as bigint)) as [Amount] 
from JobCard left join Collection on JobCard.JId=Collection.JId 
group by JobCard.JId, Collection.Amount 
order by JobCard.JId
```

Comment: then what's the problem with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `GROUP BY` clause to:

```
group by JobCard.JId
```

Comment: You can flag this as the answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your query like this, This will give you perfect result.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.test
AS
    SELECT J.JId,
           SUM(CAST(ISNULL(C.Amount, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS [Amount]
    FROM   JobCard J
           LEFT JOIN COLLECTION C
                ON  J.JId = C.JId
    GROUP BY
           J.JId
    ORDER BY
           J.JId
```

Need to remove Collection.Amount from group by clause.